# See which Roles contain a GCLOUD Permisson

Tags: google-cloud-platform, permissions

I'd like to see wich `Roles` in `iam` yield a certain permission.
In other words, for a given permission (like `billing.accounts.updateUsageExportSpec`) I want to know a list of `Roles`, that satisfy this permission.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like only the `roles/billing.admin`:
https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#billing-roles

Answer (score 0):

If under unix, with gcloud SDK you can execute the following script:

```
export expected_permission=billing.accounts.updateUsageExportSpec

for role in $(gcloud iam roles list --format='value(NAME)');                                     
do permissions=$(gcloud iam roles describe $role --format='value(includedPermissions)')
if [[ $permissions =~ $expected_permission  ]]; then echo "-------------------------------------------------" &&  echo $role && echo "-------------------------------------------------"; fi
done
```

Either way, there's [this reference](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/permissions-reference) in official docs where permission/roles mapping can be shown